# Haskell function composition on Maybe

Tags: haskell

I was studying Haskell idioms from [Blow Your Mind](https://wiki.haskell.org/Blow_your_mind)

```
-- split at whitespace
-- "hello world" -> ["hello","world"]

unfoldr (\b -> fmap (const . (second $ drop 1) . break (==' ') $ b) . listToMaybe $ b)
```

From what I know, unfoldr is supposed to be:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a,b)) -> b -> [a]
unfoldr f b = 
case f b of
  Just (a, new_b) -> a : unfoldr f new_b
  Nothing         -> []
```

So f b must output Nothing at the end, right?

So I tried to understand the f part, `fmap (const . (second $ drop 1) . break (==' ') $ b) . listToMaybe $ b)`.

I get the idea of second, drop, break, listToMaybe. But I can't figure out why composing functions like this can output Nothing.

`Const` always ignore the second parameter. So why `fmap (const . (second $ drop1) . break (==' ') $ b) . listToMaybe $ b` can output Nothing in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `(const . (second $ drop 1) . break (==' '))` is `[Char] -> b -> ([Char], [Char])`

This sophisticated function just takes a string (for example `"one two three"`) and any argument and returns `("one", "two three")`.

Therefore, `(const . (second $ drop 1) . break (==' ')) $ "one two three"` takes any argument and returns `("one", "two three")`.

`fmap (const . (second $ drop 1) . break (==' ') $ b) . listToMaybe $ b`

is the same as

`fmap (const . (second $ drop 1) . break (==' ') $ b) $ listToMaybe b`

e.g. the function is `fmapped` to a `Maybe` value, but the definition of `fmap` for `Maybe` instance is:

```
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

which means that `fmap` returns `Nothing` if `a` in `fmap f a` is `Nothing`.

`listToMaybe` returns `Just` first element of a list, or `Nothing` if the list is empty. That's why

`fmap (const . (second $ drop 1) . break (==' ') $ b) $ listToMaybe b`

will return `Nothing`, when `b` is an empty list.

Comment: Oh! So "listToMaybe b" is just an argument for fmap in order to decide cases. And according to purity, it doesn't matter to do listToMaybe inside or outside fmap. Great to know! Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

The code is written in a confusing manner. `fmap (const xyz)` basically abuses `Maybe a` as a bool switch: if it's `Just _ᴡʜᴀᴛᴇᴠᴇʀ`, the result will be `Just xyz`, while a `Nothing` is simply passed on. Such a nothing can come straight from `listToMaybe` in case of an empty list, that's how this composition can yield `Nothing`.

The preferred style of writing all this would be

```
unfoldr (\b -> listToMaybe b *> Just (second (drop 1) (break (==' ') b)))
```

or indeed with good old old `do` notation

```
unfoldr $ \b -> do
    listToMaybe b
    return . second (drop 1) $ break (==' ') b
```

But really, an explicit pattern match would be much clearer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
unfoldr $ \case
   [] -> Nothing
   b -> Just . second (drop 1) $ break (==' ') b
```

Comment: So three styles to write control process: (*>) sequence actions, do notations, and lambdaCase. And "Nothing" can stop the process. Good to learn! Thank you for advice.